# How to store postgresql database in django - project folder?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Where is postgreSQL database saved in a django folder (that which has manage.py)?

If not, I presume it must be stored in postgres folder of root directory.

Then, how to  transfer this file to those systems having no postgres installed, so that when they `run server`, they can see seamlessly all the data/app?

Can we ask DJANGO to create the database file in its project folder itself and does this help in such transfers? Thanks.

Comment: If a system does not have postgres installed then it will not be able to serve a postgres database even with the data

Comment: This quite simply isn't how postgres (or any db except sqlite) works. It's not a file, and it isn't "saved in a django folder" - or any folder. If you want portability, use sqlite instead.

Comment: No reason not to carry postgres around with you. It works even on a fairly modest linux system. I'm developing on such a system. But you configure postgres as a database service on the machine you are using. Django just sends it requests and gets responses. It's the postgres configuration that determines where it stores its DB data, which is nothing to do with Django.